# Datetime field synchronized with rails app displaying a number string in rhodes app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, rhomobile

I am using Rhoconnect for synchronizing Rails and Rhodes app. The db structure includes a datetime field along with others. when i display these records on rhodes app, the date time field (created_at) is showing '1330520025' instead of date and time.
How can i convert this to show actual date and time.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Ruby Time.strptime funcion, that is used to parse a time string. You must pass the format as the second argument. In this case the format is '%s':

```
s_time = '1330520025'
require 'time'
t = Time.strptime s_time, '%s'
```

You can format it using this function:

```
t.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
```

More details on format masks you could see in this site:
http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/2255

Comment: Thanks. But, i want the formatting to be 3/2/2012 1:02:15 PM. How can i apply this format?